# Performance Testing in Mirth Connect Using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, mirth

Mirth Connect is a software that is designed to handle a message flow and it has built-in support to handle HL7 messages in particular and therefore this software is widely used for interfacing in Healthcare applications. Over the years I have seen the Mirth software experiencing performance issues primarily due to the message build up over time and in scenarios where it receives a heavy message load in quick succession.

Mirth has a channel-based architecture and it's ideal if there is some way we can performance test the Mirth channel and get JMeter statistics for its performance. Whereby we can gather the necessary information to optimize the channel transformers and also to set the purge routines accordingly.

However in the Internet there was little to no information on this area, that is how one can use JMeter to test a Mirth channel. A team in Sri Lanka did some research on this area back in 2013 and I found their findings and achievements below
http://pragmatictestlabs.com/2016/10/09/performance-testing-healthcare-application-hl7-jmeter/

However this is very specific the output here was a JSon object which they extracted, in Mirth however we can have outputs in various forms and there need to be a better way to do this. An important takeaway from this is the input that is the input is general we can use JMeter to generate HL7 messages and pass them to Mirth that's great but how to capture the response generally, it would be ideal if there is a way to read the Mirth Dashboard through JMeter, all the output statistics are there it's just a matter of reading them.

I have an application where Mirth reads HL7 messages both ADT and RDE and creates a text file accordingly with appropriate content and drops it to a shared location. Then the application reads the files and shows the information to the user.

I wish to do two performance tests here

1. Measure how much time the complete system takes and how it varies with load from the arrival of a message to its information being available to the user
2. Measure how much time the channel takes and how it does it as the load increases

I can do the first one because I can generate HL7 messages using JMeter and I can get JMeter to read the output in the application or the database. The problem is with the second, can I do this in a general way.

Comment: I'm curious about the emphasis on JMeter as a tool to measure the performance of your Mirth instance?  Is that the tool that your sysadmins plan to use to monitor the performance of your production Mirth instance, or is there some other reason you want to use JMeter to gather performance metrics?

Answer (score 5):

You asked for suggestions, so I'm going to share my general strategy for performance testing Mirth channels.  I suspect that this won't be a complete answer to your question, and I might not be telling you anything you don't already know, but I'm hoping this will help you find an answer that you are comfortable with.

For several reasons, **try not to spend too much time "testing the complete system"**:

- Firstly, testing the entire system necessarily includes testing low-level configuration like the number of CPU cores, the NICs being used in the box, and kernel level software like the TCP/IP stack.  You don't usually have any control over these things, so you can't optimize them in any way.
- Secondly, the performance of the entire system is going to be heavily dependant on whatever ancillary code is running on the box.  If a sysadmin decides to 'nice' my Mirth process down, or to use that box to also host a SQL server, that will have an impact on the system that I (again) have no control over.
- Thirdly and most frankly, I find that the "performance of an entire system" is something that management asks about during system setup so they can get a cost estimate; but they know that they're only getting an *estimate*.  You do your best to use test metrics to give a good guess for the initial hardware provisioning, but everyone knows that it's really the production performance metrics that will drive later provisioning costs.

Make sure that you **build your channels for testability**.  I find that it's much easier to test a channel when the source and destination can be changed to "Channel Reader" and "Channel Writer" without changing message handling.  One way to look at this is that you're not going to overhaul Mirth's MLLP stack or Java's TCP stack, so just eliminate these things from your testing.

I **keep a source of useful test messages**.  I have a couple of files on a network drive that have around a hundred messages that test for nasty edge cases that I've run into over the years on my HL7 interfaces.  I wrote a small Mirth channel that reads these in from a file and spews out copies as fast as it can.  By turning on "Queueing" on the destination side of that channel, I can queue up a bajillion test messages that are ready to send to the channel I want to test.  In the past I took the time to build a test interface that acted like a fake EMR to spew out randomly constructed messages, but there didn't seem to be any advantage over just spewing copies of the same messages from my test files.

Finally, and most importantly, it's critical that you **measure the performance of your test instance using the same metrics that you'll use to measure the performance of your production instance**.  If the sole production metric you care about is 'messages per second', then that's what you need to measure on your test box.  If memory footprint is a concern in production, then you need to measure memory usage in your test environment as well.  When you make a change to to your test instance that decreases an important metric by 10%, you'll need to make sure your management is aware before you push that change to production.

Note that getting some of these metrics can be tricky, since Mirth doesn't include good tools to monitor its own performance.  The Mirth dashboard is a good place to keep an eye on errors or crashes, but it's not a great place to find performance data.  During my testing **I make sure that I use whatever resource monitoring tool that the sysadmins will be using to monitor the performance of the production instance**.  Beyond that, I use a manual process to test performance:  If I want to count message per second, I send through a batch of messages and look at the timestamps of the first and last messages.  If I want to get an idea of the CPU load of a Mirth channel, I use the Windows Performance Monitor or the posix 'top' command.

Comment: Hi Neils, 

Thank you for your answer. Actually my metrics were so far in Mirth performance testing, the number of messages per second and the time a channel takes to process a bulk of messages.

At present when I need to test a Mirth channel for performance I change the source to a file reader and change the destination to file writer and I drop to the source folder sample files. These files are sometimes HL7, XML and sometimes text files depending on the channel.

Comment: Then I look at the Mirth dashboard to see when the first file was read and see when the last was processed and thus deduce some statistics.

I know that the statistics I derive this way may not be exactly accurate and the results are often doubted and come into question as the tests are done manually. If JMeter can be used effectively for Mirth testing there will be more credibility in the test statistics.